# scroll is wrong while one section is showing on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

[**here is my DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ocahtdgv/11/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.subMenu li a').click(function () {
        jQuery('ul.subMenu li a.curM').removeClass('curM');
        jQuery(this).addClass('curM');

        var target = $(this).attr('href');

        var getHeaderHeight = jQuery(".header_wrap").height();
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $(target).offset().top - getHeaderHeight - (getHeaderHeight*!$(".header_wrap").hasClass("fixed_nav_menu"))
        }, 'fast', 'swing');


    });

    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        jQuery('.header_wrap').addClass('fixed_nav_menu');
        if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() == 0) {
            jQuery('.header_wrap').removeClass('fixed_nav_menu');
        }
        jQuery(".hidden_section").fadeIn(1500);

    });

});
```

Section named 'Third Section' in demo is showing during scroll, and because of this when you click on each section which is after it, for example 'Affiliations' you will see that it doesn't scroll to corresponding section for now to 'Affiliations' section. But **second time** when you click on menu items everything is good, it scrolls to the corresponding section.

How can I solve this, so everytime when you click on menu items fading section won't prevent to scroll corresponding section?

Comment: I dont see any issue in the jsfiddle,its scrolling to respective section all the time.

Comment: click on 'Affiliations' menu and you will see the issue @dreamweiver

Comment: ahhh, now i can see the issue. scrolling to respective section is working fine, the problem is that, as soon as any sections after `third-section` is navigated, you are `fading-in` the `third-section`, which is pushing all the sections down and showing up `third-section`. if you just remove `.hidden-section` css styles it will work fine

Comment: but in that case I can't see my section's fade effect, my issue is here that I have animated section which shows/displays while scrolling and pushing down sections. @dreamweiver

Comment: actually, your logic can show `fade-in` effect just once for `third-section` , after that it will show normally . is that what you intend to do ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88712/discussion-between-aidaghazaryan-and-dreamweiver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue In your approach :**

- Your trying to show(fade-in effect) the `third-section` div after the navigation(eg.publication section) is completed,which is why `third-section` is shown at the top of the screen instead of `publication` section.

**What have i done :**

- The `scroll` event on the window is triggered after the Navigation is completed, so the logic to show the div in `fade-in` effect is added inside `scroll` event handler.
- `Offset top` position of the target element `third-section` is checked against the current view-port position, based on that `third-section` is shown with `fade-in` effect to the user when scrolled or when navigated

---

**JS CODE:**

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.header_wrap').addClass('fixed_nav_menu');
    if ($(document).scrollTop() === 0) {
        $('.header_wrap').removeClass('fixed_nav_menu');
    }

    var top_of_object = $(".hidden_section").offset().top;
    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
    if (bottom_of_window > top_of_object) {
        $('.hidden_section').animate({
            'opacity': '1'
        }, 1500);
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden_section {
  /*display:none;*/
  opacity:0
}
```

*Note: Dont use `Jquery` & `$` both in your code, try one of the notation in your entire code base else your code will look too confusing to read.*

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/ocahtdgv/21/)